# Query selector all no me funciona

Tags: javascript

No me funciona los errores más comunes son ***getAttribute is not a function*** / ***Node was not found***  entre otros, no logro entender bien cómo es su uso ya que a ratos me funciona como quiero pero otras veces no ¿qué estoy haciendo mal? que hago para que todas las cajas pasen al otro div sin que de error y sin usar id.

```js
function mover(){
var cajas = document.querySelector(".box > div");
// Al añadir el [0] al final del query se va añadiendo de a una caja por click, es como si simplemente quitara el All, lo que necesito es que añadan todas.
document.getElementById("color").appendChild(cajas);
}
```

```css
.box{
background-color: #f1f1f1;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
.box > div{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 10px;
background-color: #ddd;
border-radius: 50%;
}
.color{
background-color: #f1f1f1;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
.color > div{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 10px;
background-color: #ff0;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>

<div id="color" class="color"></div>

<button onclick="mover()">Mover</button>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Necesitas un ciclo, puedes usar `querySelectorAll`, pero este te retorna un `Array` y para pasar todos los datos del `array` al otro `div`, sera necesario iterarlos, o hacer un ciclo ejemplo `for` o `.forEach`.
2. Una vez que ya pasas TODOS los `divs`, deberías validar que ya no encontraste otro `div` y finalizar antes de intentar pasar un objeto que no existe o es nulo.

```js
function mover(){
  var caja = document.querySelector(".box > div");
  // Al añadir el [0] al final del query se va añadiendo de a una caja por click, es como si simplemente quitara el All, lo que necesito es que añadan todas.
  if(caja){//Con esto valido si tiene valor y evito algun error al intentar asiganar un objeto que no tiene valor
    document.getElementById("color").appendChild(caja);
  }
}

function moverTodo(){
  var cajas = document.querySelectorAll(".box > div");
  //console.log(cajas);
  //Es necesario iterar el Array de datos con .forEach recorres todos los divs y haces lo que quieras con ellos dentro del ciclo, para usar forEach cajas no debe ser nulo
  if(cajas){//Con esto valido si tiene valor
    cajas.forEach(function(ele) {
      document.getElementById("color").append(ele);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.box{
background-color: #f1f1f1;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
.box > div{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 10px;
background-color: #ddd;
border-radius: 50%;
}
.color{
background-color: #f1f1f1;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
.color > div{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 10px;
background-color: #ff0;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>

<div id="color" class="color"></div>

<button onclick="mover()">Mover</button>
<button onclick="moverTodo()">Mover Todo</button>
```